# How to tell browser to not use cached resources from before date x

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The webapp is a .Net owin app and i am wondering if its possible to add some meta tags to HTML page with a date for which the browsers should download all content again and ignore cache.

I am hoping that I could put the release date into the HTML page and then the browser wont use any resources it has in cache older this this date. What other options are there? Do i need to maintain some cache header value on each javascript file?